# spinner with no select option

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to create spinner which should not have any `select` but instead of it, it should  show Blank, after clicking that items can be selected.

Here is my code, please help.

```
urineGlucoseSpinner =  (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spnner_urine_glucose);

    ArrayList<String> ugList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ugList.add(0,"");
    ugList.add("1.5");
    ugList.add("5.5");
    ugList.add("0.8");
    ugList.add("9.5");
    ugList.add("12.0");

    //ArrayAdapter<String> urineGlucoseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ugList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> urineGlucoseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner_text, ugList);
    urineGlucoseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    urineGlucoseSpinner.setAdapter(urineGlucoseAdapter);
    urineGlucoseSpinner.setSelection(0);
    urineGlucoseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnUGItemSelected());
```

Comment: is there any option to add invisible row..

Answer (score 1):

By default spinner takes array 0th element if u not selecting any one..u have to make object of ArrayList and for 0th element u have to put "" (null Sting) inside semicolon and make it as 0th element...i think this is the only solution for your question..

```
 ArrayList<String> ugList = new ArrayList<String>();
 ugList.add("");
```

Comment: thanks for reply ..i m doing this but it add's a new empty row .which is not looking good ...i want 1.5 at first place in all row.

Comment: what u exactly want on very first row..?

Comment: i want 1.5 but if 1.5 will be first row thn it will be shown in spinner directly..i want to selected it after opeing the spinner.

Comment: have you find my post helpful..i  already provide u logic..if yes then no prob on accepting answer..

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to do this.

1) Add the blank line to your data at position 0, and then create a custom spinner adapter and override the `getView` method and in it use an `if` to set the 0 position view to GONE (thus getting rid of the blank line in the listing).

2) An alternative might be setting an empty EditText in your form, and when it gains focus pop a listview in a dialog with your possible choices.

Comment: Barak..can u tell me that how can i make any spinner item disable (it should not select)

Comment: 1) did sound interesting, but does not work unfortunately. Android pre-measures the views and works with a fixed height. This will leave you with an empty container (with contains your view with visibility GONE). The drop-down list does not support different viewtypes, so this is not an option either.