# spinner with out "select option" but it should show blank

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am creating a spinner. The spinner shows the first row value as the default text.
I want the Spinner's text to be blank initially.

I could add a new empty row with `list.add(" ");` but I think that this approach looks ugly.

```
list.add("");//this make my ui ugly but with out this i can't make my spinner blank in starting.
list.add("1");//if i remove add("").then spinner take add("1") this should not happen
list.add("2");
```

How do I create a Spinner that initially doesn't display any text?

**Update:**

```
urineGlucoseSpinner =  (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spnner_urine_glucose);
ArrayList<String> ugList = new ArrayList<String>();
ugList.add("select");
ugList.add("1.5");
ugList.add("5.5");
ugList.add("0.8");
ugList.add("9.5");
ugList.add("12.0");

//ArrayAdapter<String> urineGlucoseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ugList);
ArrayAdapter<String> urineGlucoseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_spinner_text,ugList);
urineGlucoseAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
urineGlucoseSpinner.setAdapter(urineGlucoseAdapter);
urineGlucoseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnUGItemSelected());
```

Comment: What do you mean by your ui gets ugly when you put space in the first option?

Comment: means that it create a new row with empty data ..when i open the pop up .it not looks good.1- empty row 2- data row.but with out create this row i cn't make spinner blank(couse spinner takes first value by default)

Comment: A standard spinner works that way, there's not much you can do about it. You could create your own spinner, either from scratch, or by taking the source of Spinner and modify it.

Comment: if you have any option to remove that additional row but spinner should not take data row by  default .it should show blank .than guide me

Comment: Try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) tutorial may help..I had a same problem.. but as Christina said that how a spinner works, she is right

Comment: possible duplicate of [spinner with no select option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013434/spinner-with-no-select-option)

Comment: Did you try any of the ideas I gave you when you asked this question this morning?

Comment: could not success to implement that..guide me how to implement that

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? Barak is right, the linked question is exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in oncreate method:

```
Spinner gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.gender_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gender.setAdapter(adapter);
gender.setSelection(0);
```

and copy the below code and paste in string.xml

String.xml

```
<string-array name="gender_array"> 
       <item> </item>          
        <item>Male</item>        
        <item>Female</item>          
    </string-array>
```

it will work properly.

Comment: Not working its working like my code...it also contain empty row .on selection that row ,it selected also

Answer (score 0):

You should include extra entry in adapter that represents "Select" or something , and make it the initial selected item in the Spinner.

OR may be you will have to create custom spinner or something which i am not sure of.

Comment: these all the things i have done ..but no success found.................k can you guide that if i use "select" then i will also appear in list and also it will be selectable .....tell me how can i make this "select" ..unfocusable or unselectable(means when i click on "select" it should nutrul  )

Answer (score 0):

Take image look like dropdown and put them in background of textview.

```
 Textview  gender=(Textview)findViewById(R.id.gender)
  gender.setText("");
  gender.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder conductor = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Calculator.this);
                    conductor.setTitle("Select Gender");

                    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("gender_array",
                            "array", getPackageName());
                    conductor.setItems(resId,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int index) {                            
                                    int resId1 = getResources().getIdentifier(
                                            "gender_array", "array",
                                            getPackageName());

                                    gender.setText(getResources()
                                            .getStringArray(resId1)[index]);                                
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = conductor.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
            });
```

String.xml

```
<string-array name="gender_array">      
        <item>Male</item>        
        <item>Female</item>          
</string-array>
```